# PostgreSQL in Windows can't run server in background

Tags: windows, postgresql, pg-ctl

I have this problem. My OS is Windows server 2012, when I installed. postgresql-10

I open a cmd.exe windows and script it

```
pg_ctl -D "\My postgres path\10\data" start
```

Then, server is running. everything is fine.

but when I close the cmd

My postgres service is shutdown.
My pg_ctl status show：

```
pg_ctl: no server running.
```

So, how can I run postgres like linux OS

```
sudo service postgres start
```

Then it will running in the background in spite of I close the vim windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the answer.

that's easy.

only need to script it in the cmd.exe

```
pg_ctl register
```

it will register the "postgreSQL" service to the "services.msc".

then execute services.msc and enable it.

it's done !!!